# If $a<b$, $c<d$ then $a+c<b+d$?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, inequality, real-numbers

This is how I managed to prove it:

I know $a \lt b$ and $c \lt d$ thus, $b-a$ and $d-c$ are real positive numbers. Then, $b-a + d-c \gt 0$ and because of this $a+c \lt b+d$

Did I prove it right?

Comment: It seems correct to me!

Comment: You are using that $x \gt y \iff x - y \gt 0\,$, and $x \gt 0, y \gt 0 \implies x+y \gt 0\,$. Is that something you proved before, or are otherwise allowed to use?

Comment: I proved that before. But im going to include it in the proof. Thank you.

Comment: @TheNicouU If you happen to have also proved before that $x \gt y \implies x+z \gt y+z\,$, then you can just use that twice: $a+c \lt b+c \lt b+d$.

Comment: I'd just try something along the lines of if a<b than  b=xa for some value x>1, if c<d then d=yc for some value y>1  so we can rewrite the other inequality as a+c<xa+yc   and with x,y >1 ...

Comment: That's correct, but you should specifically note that $b-a+d-c=b+d-(a+c)$ to get the last step.

Comment: If the main goal of your question is checking your proof of this claim (as opposed to asking for any proof), you should probably add ([tag:proof-verification]) tag.

Comment: I will, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your way is correct,another one is 
add both side $c$ to the $a<b$ so that $$a+c<b+c\\ $$ 
then add $b$ to the $c<d$ so that $$c+b<d+b$$
finally we can conclude that $$a+c<b+d$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Formalizing, you might write something like:

$$(a<b)\land(c<d)$$
$\implies$ (using $x<y\iff x+z<y+z$)
$$(0<b-a)\land(0<d-c)$$
$\implies$ (using $x<y\iff x+z<y+z$)
$$(d-c<b-a+(d-c))\land(0<d-c)$$
$\implies$ (transitivity)
$$0<b-a+(d-c)$$
$\implies$ (using $x<y\iff x+z<y+z$ and associativity of addition)
$$a+c<b+d$$

Comment: But that is not the axiom system OP is using. The OPs proof is assuming the existence of a set of "positive" values, with certain properties, and defines $a<b$ as "$b-a$ is a positive value."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't quite understand. How do you know this isn't the axiom system the OP is using? It's not stated in the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews To me, '$b−a$ is a positive value' $\equiv$ '$b-a>0$'. ie. $a<b\iff 0<b-a$

Answer (score -2):

I would like to give a sweet and simple proof:

- $a$ < $b$ ---------------------(1)
- $c$ < $d$ ---------------------(2)
- now simply add the two equations:
- $a+c$ < $b+d$
- ***hope it helps you!***

Comment: This is maybe the intuition behind the OP's statement, but it is nowhere near a proper proof.