# Prove that if $a < b$ and $c < d$ then $a + c < b + d$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I'm having a tough time with this questions. Could someone perhaps give me a hint? I'm only allowed to use the axioms of real numbers:

A1. $a + b = b + a$

A2. $a + (b + c) = (a+b) + c$

A3. $a + 0 = a$

A4. $a + (-a) = 0$

M1. $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$

M2. $a \cdot (b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$

M3. $a \cdot 1 = a$

M4. if $a \neq 0$ then $a \cdot \frac{1}{a} = 1$

D. $a \cdot (b+c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c$

Comment: This has already been answered here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400679/if-ab-cd-then-acbd

Comment: Thank you! I searched for it, but somehow didn't find it!

Answer (score 1):

Use $x < y\iff x + d < y+d$, to prove that $a < b \iff a+c < b+ c$ and to prove that $c< d \iff b + c < b + d$.

and finish it off with $x < y; y< z \implies x < z$.

to prove $a + c < b+c$ and $b+c  < b+d\implies a+c < b+d$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote the set $\mathbb{P}$ as the positive real numbers. We define $a<b$ and $c<d$ in the following ways:

- $b-a\in\mathbb{P}\equiv a<b$
- $d-c\in\mathbb{P}\equiv c<d$

So if we assume the above, then certainly $$(b-a)+(d-c)\in\mathbb{P}\implies(b+d)-(a+c)\in\mathbb{P}\implies a+c<b+d$$