# Properties of Two Inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, integers

If $a < b$ and $c < d$, then $a + c < b + d$ if $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers.

My hunch is that this is true, but I'm having difficulty proving it.  Is there a property or definition pertaining to inequalities that exists to support/disprove the above?

Comment: True for all reals, not just positives or integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $a<b$, $c<d$ then $a+c<b+d$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400679/if-ab-cd-then-acbd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a < b \implies a+c < b+c$

$c < d \implies b+c < b+d$

So $a < b$ and $c<d \implies a+c < b+c < b+d \implies a+c < b+d$

Answer (score 1):

From the axioms of an ordered field, $a<b \implies a+c<b+c$, and $c<d\implies b+c<b+d.$

Therefore,  $a+c<b+c<b+d.$

Comment: positive integers are in the ordered field $\mathbb R$; also used the transitive property of $<$